# Assuming that the ball bounces indefinitely, find the total distance that the ball travels.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A ball has the property that each time it falls a distance onto a hard, level surface it rebounds to a height $rh$ where $0< r <1$. Suppose that the ball is dropped from an initial height of $H$ meters. Assuming that the ball bounces indefinitely, find the total distance that the ball travels.
Write your answer both with sigma notation and as a closed formula

This is the work I've done to reach sigma notation and the closed formula:

$a_{1}=H$

$a_{2}=2Hr$

$a_{3}=2Hr^{2}$

$a_{4}=2Hr^{3}$

$a_{n}=2Hr^{n-1}$

$s_{n}=H+2Hr+2Hr^{2}+...+2Hr^{n-1}$

Is the sigma notation:

$H+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2Hr^{n-1}=2Hr+2Hr^{2}+2Hr^{3}+...+2Hr^{n-1}$

geometric series: $\frac{a_{1}}{1-r}$

$a = 2Hr$

$r = r$

$H + 2Hr$

$H + \frac{2Hr}{1-r}$

$\frac{H(1-r)+2Hr)}{1-r}$

$\frac{H-rH+2Hr}{1-r}$

$H\frac{1-r+2r}{1-r}$

Closed form:
$Distance = H(\frac{1+r}{1-r})$

Does this all look correct?

Comment: **Clarification needed**: "A ball has the property that each time it falls a distance onto a hard, level surface it rebounds to a height $r$ where $0< r <1$" : As stated, each rebound is the absolute distance $r$, so the total rebounding (ignoring falling distance) is $r + r + r + \cdots.$  This is **clearly not intended** : what is probably intended is that the **ratio** of the rebound to the height is $r$.  **To the OP**: Assuming that you agree, please edit the query.

Comment: Added an edit, it rebounds to a height $rh$ where $0<r<1$

Answer (score 1):

It seems your difficulty arises because you are doing the parts of the problem in the wrong order. Sigma notation is supposed to be the easy part of the problem, the part that you can do as soon as you understand how to write the $n$th term of the sum,
**before** you figure out what the closed form of the sum is.

If you can write

$$ s_{n}=H+2Hr+2Hr^{2}+...+2Hr^{n-1} $$

then you should be able to write a $\sum$ notation relevant to the question.
(The first term doesn't fit the right pattern for the $\sum$ notation,
but based on your later work I think you know this and you know how to deal with it.)

The equation
$$ar^{n-1} \stackrel?= \frac{a}{1-r}$$
is plainly and clearly false; just try a few different choices of numbers,
for example $a = 1,$ $r = \frac12,$ $n = 4$ and see how wrong it is.
Remember that when you write $ar^{n-1}$ you are saying to just take $r$ to the $n-1$ power, multiply by $a,$ and then stop and that's your answer.

If you wrote the left side of the equation with $\frac{a}{1-r}$ correctly, it would already be in $\sum$ notation.

Forget about everything you wrote after $\frac{a}{1-r}$ and just try to write the summations for these two places. You might have to look up the  $\frac{a}{1-r}$ to remind yourself this time.

Comment: So I think I figured out the sigma notation: $H + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2Hr^{n-1}$
But now I'm unsure with how to get it into a closed formula